# How to use jQuery to remove class from every element on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove a specific CSS class from every element on the page. Would I just do something like:

```
$(body).removeClass('removethis');
$(body).each().removeClass('removethis');
```

I don't know the correct way to do this. I am doing this to automatically remove a class from every element on the page when javascript is enabled.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a single class on the body, rather than tagging every element with a "no-js" identifier.

Comment: I only use this like 2 or 3 times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(".removeThis").removeClass("removeThis");
```

That will remove the class from every element that has that class.